# Create a view with multiple foreign key referencing a single field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

How can I create a view using a table which has multiple foreign key referencing the same table and a single field. I have product table and Reference table I have around 5 foreign key in product table referencing to the `RefCodeKey` Field in reference table. How can I create a view which shows product reference Code joining product and Reference Code

I have a product table as follows

```
   PK  PTK   PC      PN    RCKey PSKey PCKey PCAKey
    1   1   500000  Prod A  5    12     14  98
    2   1   500001  Prod B  5    12     14  98
    3   1   500002  Prod C  5    11     13  145
    4   4   500002  Prod C  10   11     13  76
    5   3   500002  Prod C  10   11     13  95
    6   1   500005  Prod D  5    12     14  137
```

I have Reference Code Table as follows

```
RefCodeKey  RefCodeType        Code        Label       Status
1       ParentTypeKey         assembly      assembly   Active
2       ParentTypeKey           WHL          WHL       Active
3       ParentTypeKey           TIRE        TIRE       Active
4       ParentTypeKey           TIRE        TIRE       Active
5       RegionCodeKey           1           COMP 1     Active
6       RegionCodeKey           2           COMP 2     Active
7       RegionCodeKey           3           COMP 3     Active
8       RegionCodeKey           4           COMP 4     Active
9       RegionCodeKey           9           COMP 5     Active
10      RegionCodeKey           0           COMP 6     Active
11      ProductStatusKey        CLOSED      CLOSED     Active
12      ProductStatusKey        ACTIVE     ACTIVE   Active
13      ProductClassificationKey DropShip   DropShipActive
14      ProductClassificationKey INFO NA    INFO NA Active
```

How can i create a view display a result as show below?

```
PC        PN    RCKey PSKey   PCKey
500000  Prod A  COMP 1  ACTIVE  INFO NA 
500001  Prod B  COMP 1  ACTIVE  INFO NA 
500002  Prod C  COMP 1  CLOSED  DropShip    
500002  Prod C  COMP 6  CLOSED  DropShip    
500002  Prod C  COMP 6  CLOSED  DropShip    
500005  Prod D  COMP 1  ACTIVE  INFO NA
```

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common reporting pattern wherever the database architect has employed the "[one true lookup table](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql/)" model. I'm not going to get bogged down in the merits of that design. People like Celko and Phil Factor are far more erudite than me at commenting on these things. All I'll say is that having reported off over sixty enterprise databases in the last 15 years, that design is pervasive. Rightly or wrongly, you're probably going to see it over and over again.

There is currently insufficient information to definitively answer your question. The answer below makes assumptions on what I think is the most likely missing information is.

1. I'll assume your product table is named PRODUCT
2. I'll assume your all-powerful lookup table is call REFS
3. I'll assume RefCodeKey in REFS has a unique constraint on it, or it is the a primary key
4. I'll assume the REFS table is relatively small (say < 100,000 rows). I'll come back to this point later.
5. I'll assume that the foreign keys in the PRODUCT table are nullable. This affects whether we INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN.

   ```
   SELECT prod.PC
          ,prod.PN
          ,reg_code.label  as RCKey
          ,prod_stat.label as PSKey
          ,prod_clas.label as PCKey
   FROM   PRODUCT             prod
          LEFT JOIN REFS  reg_code ON prod.RCKey = reg_code.RefCodeKey
          LEFT JOIN REFS prod_stat ON prod.PSKey = prod_stat.RefCodeKey
          LEFT JOIN REFS prod_clas ON prod.PCKey = prod_clas.RefCodeKey
   ;
   ```

The trick is that you can refer to the REFS table as many times as you like. You just need to give it a different alias and join it to the relevant FK each time. For example `reg_code` is an alias. Give your aliases meaningful names to keep your code readable.

**Note:** Those RCKey/PSKey/PCKey names are really not good names. They'll come back to bite you. They don't represent the key. They represent a description of the thing in question. If it's a region code, call it region_code

The reason I'm assuming the REFS table is relatively small, is that if it's really large (I've seen one with 6 million lookup values across hundreds of codesets) and indexed to take RefCodeType into consideration, you might get better performance by adding a filter for RefCodeType to each of your LEFT JOINs. For example:

```
       LEFT JOIN REFS prod_clas ON prod.PCKey = prod_clas.RefCodeKey
                                   AND prod_clas.RefCodeType = 'ProductClassificationKey'
```